# How to individually control ~100 LEDs

Tags: led

I am trying to do a project which requires me to control about 100 LEDs individually. I want to make a clock that has 6 columns of 10 LEDs that as the number in the time goes up, more LEDs will turn on. I would prefer just doing it with wires connected directly to the lights. I have looked into using an arduino, but they don’t have enough ports. Is there any way to do this? Maybe using USB?

Thanks,
djtravz

Comment: What power? What's the physical arrangement of the LEDs?

Comment: there is always a way, except that you have not described the project, so it is impossible to guess which way would be best.

Comment: Depending on power requirements, and required speed, you might just need 20 pins (hint: 20 = 2*sqrt(# of leds)).

Comment: I updated the post @jsotola and Jonathan

Comment: *" I would prefer just doing it with wires connected directly to the lights. "* That would be 100 outputs. You know there are more efficient ways. Also 6 columns of 10 LEDs I get to 60 LEDs, not 100.

Answer (score 4):

A few choices:

- You can use shift-registers such as HC595 to drive individual LEDs,
  one resistor in series with each. Needs only 4 port pins from your
  MCU, but n resistor and n/8 (rounded up) chips. It would be static
  drive.
- You can use individually addressable RGB(W) LEDs and add color to
  your project. Still only a few port pins. Libraries are available for
  this purpose.
- You could build row and common drivers and multiplex the LEDs fast
  enough that they appear to be steady. Time-tested approach, works
  well. You could use (say) 8 column drivers and 8 row drivers to
  control 64 LEDs.

Personally, for a hobby project, I would probably pick door #2.

Comment: Door #2: There are Arduino libraries for the very common & cheap WS2812 LEDs.

Comment: The RGB LEDs which Wouter is referring to include a driver chip with serial (and daisy-chain-able) interface. Thanks to China they are very affordable, thanks to open-source libraries they are easy to use despite the somewhat arcane interface.

Comment: Or option 4, build a matrix with discrete row and column drivers (demux for one, shift registers for the other). Could even use a counter to drive the demux, or use a shift register and only shift by one position at a time. More efficient in terms of IO pins.

Answer (score 1):

These two solution also have dimming.

Use a matrix design like the Texas Instruments 96 LED driver: [LED17 1596A 96-LED Matrix Driver](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/led171596a.pdf) (get some free samples)

[image]

---

If you were to use a 3 output serial RGB drivers like the  
Texas Instruments [TLC59731 3-Channel, 8-Bit, PWM LED Driver With Single-Wire Interface](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc59731.pdf) 

or [WS2811](https://auschristmaslighting.com/wiki_source/images/b/ba/WS2811.pdf)  , you do not have to use the 3 channels for RGB but rather any 3 LEDs.

---

[EDN Tips and tricks for driving WS2811 LED strips](https://www.edn.com/design/led/4438797/Tips-and-tricks-for-driving-WS2811-LED-strips---Part-1)

---

[image]

---

[image]